# Does Ember CLI Mirage store data in a database? or the posted data gets removed after refreshing the browser?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli, ember-cli-mirage

I am a newbie to ember and i am using ember cli mirage for servers side API. For example, i want to POST a movie to the movies route, it gets added to the existing one's present in fixtures and is listed in localhost-4200/movies.
On refreshing the browser, the one's posted gets erased and the default one's remain.
Is this the expected behavior ?? Won't the details remain the same after browser refresh or when i reload the next time?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is the expected behavior. Fixtures will be applied on pageload.

> Mirage was created to let you easily fake your JSON API. It's built on existing libraries, but brings along conventions to make setting up your fake server quick and painless.

Mirage is not a production API, it fakes your API for easy development and testing, but if you need a persistend API, you need to write one by yourself.

If you want to start building a server, but you dont know where to start, take a look at https://github.com/emberjs/data and JSON-API server implementations: http://jsonapi.org/implementations/